# Trouble to connect Cassandra Nodes to each other

Tags: cassandra

I would like to start my first steps with Apache Cassandra and looked/read a lot of tutorials but i am unable to connect two Cassandra aplications to each other...
May some of you can help me...
I have 1 Windows 2012 Server running Cassandra 3.5 and a Ubuntu 14 running Cassandra 3.5, too. On both Servers, i can run the ./nodetool status and get the status that all is working fine on the own IP adress. This apears on both Servers. But the Cassandra Applications cant find each other.
Below you will find some snippets of the *.yaml Config.
====Windows Yaml config=====

> class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider 
>         parameters: 
>             # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses. 
>             - seeds: "172.16.17.21,172.16.17.22" // these are my two internal IP Adresses (21=windows 22=Ubuntu)
>
> listen_adress: 172.16.17.21 rpc_address:0.0.0.0 broadcast_rpc_address
>   172.16.17.0 and finaly SimpleSnitch
>
> This Config looks similar to the Ubuntu Config expect i set the
>   listen_address to 172.16.17.22.

What do i wrong?
Did i forgot to make any preconfigurations on the Servers/Networks?
May some of you can help me please...
Greetings Marvin

Comment: additinal to say... when i start ./cqlsh i got the message for a sucessfully connection to the Clustername, but on my localhost IP (127.0.0.1:9042)... this looks not correctly to me....

Comment: `broadcast_rpc_address 172.16.17.0` looks wrong to me. I would guess that is the default gateway of your network? Try setting the broadcast address to the same IP as the `listen_address`.

Comment: thx for the answer, but it doesnt work, too... i also changed the broadcast_rpc_adress to 1.2.3.4, as in some tutorials. and also changed endpoint_snitch to "RackInferringSnitch", always the same... :( just one Cassandra Node apears...

Comment: 1.2.3.4 is a sample IP address that for sure makes no sense in your case. Can you telnet from one machine to the other on the Cassandra port?

Comment: it looks like it works on Port 9042 but not on the rpc port 9160. Windows to Ubuntu :"Telnet 172.16.17.22 9042" i got a new black window </br> Ubuntu to Windows "Telent 172.16.17.21 9042" i got "connected to 172.16.17.21" Other No Connection

Comment: So you can connect from machine A to B but not vice versa? If that is the case, try disabling all firewalls on those machines for the purpose of the test.

Comment: Yes! that was the problem... All runs fine and whne i started nodetool i see both Cassandra instances running on 100% :) thx Alot